# pass a string with non printable char in hexa to a

Tags: command-line, python

I want to pass a string in hexa :

> 'c3:87:80:00'

by instance to a binary
I've tried :

```
./<bin> "$(python -c "print 'c3:87:80:00'")"
```

and

```
./<bin> "$(printf 'c3:87:80:00')"
```

I've also copy paste the string result of it from an hexa converter but it doesn't work better

Comment: "pass a string with non printable char in hexa to a"...? Binary? Also, it might be my fault but I fail to see what is not working/what result you are expecting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `\xc3:\x87:\x80:\x00` instead of `c3:87:80:00`.
Where `\x` represent hex data